# What happens to a block at compile time, and can I create one at runtime?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, introspection

This is a two-part question about *blocks* (^{}) in *Objective-C*. I have searched for some answers, but nothing has showed up in Google or SO. This question stems from a desire to create an custom XML Layout Engine for iOS, with support for blocks - meaning that I want to parse NSStrings and create a block during runtime.

1) Is this even possible? If so, how can it be done?

Not being able to find much on `NSString to Block`, I thought that the reason may be how a block is handled by the compiler - so again I searched for an answer but came up empty-handed. So:

2) What happens to a block at compile time in Objective-C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A block is two things;  a hunk of executable code and state captured at the moment when execution passes over the block.

I.e. given:

```
 myBlock = ^{ return someVariable + someOtherVariable; };
```

When compiled, this creates a chunk of code that acts very much like a function that adds two variables together returns the result.   No block instance is created.

When executing, when the expression `myBlock = ^{...};` is evaluated, then a block instance is created.  Inside that block instance is a reference to the code the compiler created and a copy of the values contained in the two variables *at the time the assignment to `myBlock` was made* (unless, of course, `__block` is in play, etc...).

That answers (2), but is relevant to answering (1).

At runtime, you can create instances of existing, compiled, blocks all day long.  You cannot, however, create new *kinds* of blocks.    Doing so would require a compiler and would be limited to runtime environments where compiling new executable code and actually executing it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

What you can't easily do is compile Objective-C code at run-time to create blocks. What you can do is create a small parser for your layout DSL and create a tree of blocks. For example a  mathematical expression parser could be implemented using nested blocks.

Here is an example for the expresion "2 + 3 * 4":

```
typedef double(^MathBlock)(void);

MathBlock exprL = ^(void) { return 3.0; };
MathBlock exprR = ^(void) { return 4.0; };

exprR = ^(void) { return exprL() * exprR();  };
exprL = ^(void) { return 2.0; };

exprR = ^(void) { return exprL() + exprR();  };

double result = exprR();
```

Obviously, you will need to write parsing functions interpret your XML to return these blocks. This is particularly simple with recursive descent parsers.

Answer (score 0):

1) if you mean to compile a block at run time, no. Compiler is not available at run time.
2) obviously, a block is compiled at compile time. It is executable code at run time, like a function or a method or a part of any of them. But blocks are compiled in a way they can be sent for post execution and handling block vars magic.