# Can you append code to an Objective-C block variable?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I want to dynamically add code to a block variable, or merge or concatenate a block with another block. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens to a block at compile time, and can I create one at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323089/what-happens-to-a-block-at-compile-time-and-can-i-create-one-at-runtime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this possible?

No, but you can create a collection of blocks and execute them sequentially.

Comment: Would you give an example of assigning a block to a collection? Would it need to be a c-array since a block is not an obj? Or can you somehow wrap a block within another object for storage into a NSMutableArray?

Comment: No wrapping required -- [a block is an Objective-C object](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH3-SW2). You can [store them in an NSArray](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7997666/643383) (or other Obj-C collection), or you can create another block that takes two or more blocks as parameters and executes them one after another, as dasblinkenlight has nicely illustrated.

Comment: How can we know when the block at index n has completed so that we can move onto n+1?

Comment: I think you're thinking that blocks always run asynchronously, but that's not the case at all. If you have a block assigned to a variable, you can invoke the block using the variable just like you would with a function pointer: `for (MyBlockType someBlock in listOfBlocks) { someBlock(); }` Async execution really only happens if you run the block on another thread or queue, like when you use GCD's `dispatch_async()` function to invoke the block.

Comment: you had me at 'i think youre thinking that blocks always run asynchronously' ;)

Answer (score 5):

One way of doing it is creating a block that calls the block to be "expanded" before performing its own functions.

For example, consider the example below that adds logging functionality to an arbitrary block passed into it:

```
typedef void (^MyBlock)(int);

-(MyBlock) expand:(MyBlock)nested {
    return ^(int x) {
        nested(x);
        NSLog("The value of x = %d", x);
    };
}
```

The cumulative effect of calling the block produced by `expand:` is that of invoking the original block, followed by an operation from the expanded block. You can take it further, to create an `appendBlock` method:

```
-(MyBlock) appendBlock:(MyBlock)second toBlock:(MyBlock)first {
    return ^(int x) {
        first(x);
        second(x);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure - just create a new block, which makes use of the original in whatever compositional way you'd like. If you've got `block1` and `block2`, you might create:

```
   someCodeBefore = ^myBlockType(block1) {
     someCode()
     thatIWantBefore();
     block1();
   }

   someCodeAfter = ^myBlockType(block1) {
     block1();
     someCode()
     thatIWantAfterBlock1();
   }

   composedBlocks = ^myBlockType(block1, block2) {
     block1();
     block2();
   }
```

Just make sure you're copying the blocks correctly.

Comment: That's really not the same as merging/concatenating blocks together. You still have separate blocks, each with its own state, rather than a single block with shared state.

Comment: But, as blocks are opaque, what would it mean to "share state"? You couldn't see any of it even if it were shared.

Comment: Exactly -- you can use blocks in combination, and you can have a single block that contains other blocks, but you can't *merge* two blocks into a single block (which is what I understood the OP to be asking about).